# Vigenere Cipher Python 2.0

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, vigenere

Im having trouble with encoding / decoding programming for a vigenere cipher. Im only supposed to use lists, dictionaries and loops.
EDIT: I added in the decrypt i have. GetCharList() just gets a list containing the alphabet. I dont know what is wrong that its making the output of the decrpyt not the original message.

```
def encryptVig(msg, keyword):
    alphabet = getCharList() #Get char list is another function which creates a list containing a - z
    key = keyword.upper()
    keyIndex = 0 
    dicList = []
    for symbol in msg:
        num = alphabet.find(key[keyIndex])
        if num != -1:
            num += alphabet.find(key[keyIndex])
            alphabet.find(key[keyIndex])
            num%= len(alphabet)
            if symbol.isupper():
                dicList.append(alphabet[num])
        elif symbol.islower():
            dicList. append(alphabet[num].lower())
        keyIndex += 1
        if keyIndex == len(key):
            keyIndex = 0
        else:
            dicList.append(symbol)
return " " .join(dicList)

def decryptVig(msg, keyword):
    getCharList()
    key = keyword.upper()
    keyIndex = 0 
    dicList = []
    for symbol in msg:
        num = alphabet.find(key[keyIndex])
        if num != -1:
            num -= alphabet.find(key[keyIndex])
            alphabet.find(key[keyIndex])
            num%= len(alphabet)
            if symbol.isupper():
            dicList.append(alphabet[num])
        elif symbol.islower():
            dicList. append(alphabet[num].lower())
        keyIndex -= 1
        if keyIndex == len(key):
            keyIndex = 0
        else:
            dicList.append(symbol)
return " " .join(dicList)
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are having?

Comment: So basically we can't run your stuff and you have some problem but you don't tell us what it is ?!

Comment: When I encode, it produces an output such as Q O Q O O Q
WHen i decode it with the decode function which is basically the same function with the + into - to reverse the cipher, it doesnt decrypt the message.

Comment: If the problem is with the `decrypt` then you should post that function.

Comment: Posted the decrypt :\ any help that would lead me in the right direction is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than hacking through the alphabet yourself, another approach would be to use `ord` and `chr` to remove some of the complexity of working with letters.  At the very least consider using `itertools.cycle` and `itertools.izip` to construct a list of the encryption/decryption pairs.  Here's how I would solve it:

```
def letters_to_numbers(str):
    return (ord(c) - ord('A') for c in str)

def numbers_to_letters(num_list):
    return (chr(x + ord('A')) for x in num_list)

def gen_pairs(msg, keyword):
    msg = msg.upper().strip().replace(' ', '')
    msg_sequence = letters_to_numbers(msg)
    keyword_sequence = itertools.cycle(letters_to_numbers(keyword))
    return itertools.izip(msg_sequence, keyword_sequence)

def encrypt_vig(msg, keyword):
    out = []
    for letter_num, shift_num in gen_pairs(msg, keyword):
        shifted = (letter_num + shift_num) % 26
        out.append(shifted)
    return ' '.join(numbers_to_letters(out))

def decrypt_vig(msg, keyword):
    out = []
    for letter_num, shift_num in gen_pairs(msg, keyword):
        shifted = (letter_num - shift_num) % 26
        out.append(shifted)
    return ' '.join(numbers_to_letters(out))

msg = 'ATTACK AT DAWN'
keyword = 'LEMON'
print(encrypt_vig(msg, keyword))
print(decrypt_vig(encrypt_vig(msg, keyword), keyword))

>>> L X F O P V E F R N H R
    A T T A C K A T D A W N
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how Vigenere is supposed to work. However I am quite sure that after

```
    num = alphabet.find(key[keyIndex])
    if num != -1:
        num -= alphabet.find(key[keyIndex])
```

`num` is zero.